# Paired or independent samples test when doing computer simulation experiment

Tags: simulation

I am doing a computer simulation experiment on two different operating systems (OS1,OS2), comparing performance (Measure 1, Measure 2) of two software products (P1,P2) under simulated stress conditions (S1,S2,S3). I need to compare both products on the same OS and one product on both OSs. Each stress environment (S1,S2,S3) is simulated 50 times.

For S1 & M1 (same thing repeats for S2 & M1, S1 & M2, etc)

P1: OS1 v OS2
P2: OS1 v OS2

OS1: P1 v P2
OS2: P1 v P2

Comparison between two products is done for each stress environment separately (S1,S2,S3). As I understand my example, these are completely independent samples and I should use independent samples T-test in case of normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental unit in this case is a computer *run*.  You change the conditions (OS, Product, Stress Environment) and conduct a *run* or series of *runs* under those conditions.

Since each set of *runs* has no logical pairing, these would be independent samples.  As an easy way to identify independent samples rather than pairs, ask yourself the question:  Could there be unequal sample sizes in each group?  In this case, the answer is yes; you could conceivably conduct 50 *runs* under one set of conditions and 100 *runs* under a different set.  This is an intuitive way to see that the samples cannot be paired, and therefore must be independent.